# autoincrement on oracle (necessary to add this statement?)

Tags: oracle11g, sequence, auto-increment

Do we need to add auto increment statement for the primary key? if so, how does it managed?

I've created a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDIO
(STUDIOID NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2(20),
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
PHONE NUMBER(11),
URL VARCHAR2(20),
CONSTRAINT STUDIO_STUDIOID_pk PRIMARY KEY(STUDIOID));
```

---

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE STUDIO_SEQ
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 10;
```

I haven't define a type for the `studioid` since it is going to be valued in studio_seq sequence that I've added for this table.

my question is, should I also write auto increment, anywhere in this table above?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [create table with sequence.nextval in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

you must use trigger like

```
create or replace TRIGGER STUDIO_trg 
BEFORE INSERT
ON STUDIO 
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   tmpvar   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   tmpvar := 0;
   SELECT SEQUENCE STUDIO_SEQ.NEXTVAL
     INTO tmpvar
     FROM DUAL;

   :NEW.STUDIOID := tmpvar;
END TRIGGER STUDIO_trg;
```