# How to use Oracle Sequence Numbers in DBUnit?

Tags: dbunit

How can I used Oracle Sequences to auto-generate primary keys for my tables while exporting data into Oracle using DBUnit ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/pull/30). It seems a potential solution although not out-of-box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and didn't find any answer. I ended up using a trigger to automatically generate the technical key, as described  in this post [create table with sequence.nextval in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ticketSequenceTrigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON TICKET
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.id IS null)
  DECLARE
    v_id TICKET.id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT TICKET_ID_SEQ.nextval INTO v_id FROM DUAL;
    :new.id := v_id;
  END ticketSequenceTrigger;
```

Then I simply ommit the id column in the initial and expected datasets:

```
<ticket title="Ticket 1"
        description="Description for ticket 1"
        status="NEW"
        created_date="2013-07-01 12:00:00"/>
```