# cannot find function or procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to debug an Oracle procedure code but I am new to Oracle. In the procedure I see a line of code like the following, but I cannot locate its implementation in order figure out what it's doing.

```
select SOME_OBJECT_OR_PACKAGE.NEXTVAL into some_var from dual;
```

It looks like it's calling a function from a package to me but I don't see a package with that name in the Packages folder from SQL Developer. I have tried the following command but got nothing in return.

```
select * from all_source where UPPER(name) like UPPER('%SOME_OBJECT_OR_PACKAGE%')
```

Please help.

Comment: search all_objects, you'll see your sequence there. You can also find it SQL Developer, under the sequences node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEXTVAL is way to retrieve the next value in a SEQUENCE in Oracle.

see here for more details:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

or here:
[Create Table With Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

It's a database object called a sequence.  It auto-increments when you select it.