# Sequence in Oracle/PostgreSQL with no ID in insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, sequence, ddl

I'm try to create table with clever sequence generator for using this insert-strucure:

```
insert into SOMEUSERS (SOMEUSERS_NAME, SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD) 
values ('Artem', 'PracTimPatie');
```

instead of this:

```
insert into SOMEUSERS (SOMEUSERS_ID, SOMEUSERS_NAME, SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD) 
values (2, 'Artem', 'PracTimPatie');
```

or this structure:

```
insert into SOMEUSERS (SOMEUSERS_ID, SOMEUSERS_NAME, SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD) 
values (GEN_ID_SOMEUSERS.nextval, 'Artem', 'PracTimPatie');
```

When I executing the following sql script:

```
create sequence gen_id_someUsers START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;

CREATE TABLE loc_db.someUsers
( someUsers_id number(10) DEFAULT gen_id_someUsers.NEXTVAL NOT NULL, --because of this row
  someUsers_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  someUsers_password varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT someUsers_pk PRIMARY KEY (someUsers_id)
);
```

the following notice is given to me:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
>   00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

For clarity, said that in this case:

```
    ...
CREATE TABLE loc_db.someUsers
( someUsers_id number(10) NOT NULL, --correct this row
...
```

> Sequence GEN_ID_SOMEUSERS created.
>
> Table LOC_DB.SOMEUSERS created.

### ***How can I configure comfortable sequence generator?***

(in case of **PostgreSQL too**. If possible with no trigger(as easily as possible)

Comment: In Postgres, just define the column as `serial`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL You can't use a sequence as a default in Oracle up until 11g. You *have* to use a trigger in that version. In Oracle 12g, you can actually use a syntax quite similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 12c introduces [Identity columns](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAECCFH):

```
CREATE TABLE SOMEUSERS (
  SOMEUSERS_ID       NUMBER(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                     CONSTRAINT SOMEUSERS__SOMEUSERS_ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  SOMEUSERS_NAME     VARCHAR2(50)
                     CONSTRAINT SOMEUSERS__SOMEUSERS_NAME__NN NOT NULL,
  SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

If you want to do it in earlier versions then you will need a trigger and a sequence:

```
CREATE TABLE SOMEUSERS (
  SOMEUSERS_ID       NUMBER(10)
                     CONSTRAINT SOMEUSERS__SOMEUSERS_ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  SOMEUSERS_NAME     VARCHAR2(50)
                     CONSTRAINT SOMEUSERS__SOMEUSERS_NAME__NN NOT NULL,
  SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE SEQUENCE gen_id_someUsers START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOMEUSERS__ID__TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON SOMEUSERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.SOMEUSERS_ID := gen_id_someUsers.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

You can then just do (either with the identity column or the trigger combined with your sequence):

```
INSERT INTO SOMEUSERS (
  SOMEUSERS_NAME,
  SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD
) VALUES (
  'Name',
  'Password'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In postgres just use a serial like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SOMEUSERS (
  SOMEUSERS_ID serial NOT NULL,
  SOMEUSERS_NAME text,
  SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD text
);
```

Your insert statement is then easy as:

```
INSERT INTO SOMEUSERS (SOMEUSERS_NAME, SOMEUSERS_PASSWORD) 
values ('Artem', 'PracTimPatie');
```

If you wanna query the sequence you can just query it like any other relation.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have addressed postgreSQL and Oracle 12c, so I'll address Oracle 11.2 or earlier here.

From the 11.1 SQL Reference Manual:

> DEFAULT
>
> The DEFAULT clause lets you specify a value to be assigned to the column if a subsequent INSERT statement omits a value for the column. The datatype of the expression must match the datatype of the column. The column must also be long enough to hold this expression.
>
> The DEFAULT expression can include any SQL function as long as the function does not return a literal argument, a column reference, or a nested function invocation.
>
> **Restriction on Default Column Values**
>
> A DEFAULT expression **cannot contain references to** PL/SQL functions or to other columns, the pseudocolumns CURRVAL, **NEXTVAL**, LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date constants that are not fully specified.

(Emphasis mine)

So since you can't put `sequence.NEXTVAL` in as a DEFAULT value you're basically going to have to use a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOMEUSERS_BI
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON LOC_DB.SOMEUSERS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.SOMEUSERS_ID THEN
    :NEW.SOMEUSERS_ID := GEN_ID_SOMEUSERS.NEXTVAL;
  END IF;
END SOMEUSERS_BI;
```

In my experience there is no reliable alternative to using a trigger such as this in Oracle 11.2 or earlier.

Best of luck.