# How can I insert a sequence number automatically in Oracle Sql?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, auto-increment

I have some table and trying load data into it by selecting row from another table like below.

```
insert into emp2(eid,ename,sal,my_seq_num) select eid,ename,sal from emp1;
```

When I executed the   above query I am getting the error 'not enough values' because I selected only three rows but insert contains 4 columns .So my question is how can Insert a sequence number automatically (like we write SYSDATE to write into date column)  .

Comment: look for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into emp2(eid,ename,sal,my_seq_num) 
select eid,ename,sal,sequence_name.nextval 
from emp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

insert into emp2(eid,ename,sal,my_seq_num) select eid,ename,sal,mention your 
sequence name from emp1;

For example :-
insert into emp2(eid,ename,sal,my_seq_num) select eid,ename,sal,my_seq_num.nextval from emp1;

Answer (score 0):

First, you need create a [SEQUENCE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) object

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
  MINVALUE value
  MAXVALUE value
  START WITH value
  INCREMENT BY value
  CACHE value;
```

In your case:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

Then, you can get the next number in the sequence with `nextval`, like:

```
SELECT my_sequence.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

In your `INSERT`:

```
insert into emp2(eid,ename,sal,my_seq_num) 
select eid,ename,sal,my_sequence.NEXTVAL from emp1;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi @David Isla ,Thank you so much for ur reply.And I have two more doubts here.1) Does Create sequence work  in every database (like MySQL,SQL,SYBASE etc ..)?.   2)How can I Create this sequence from from Java program?

Comment: `SEQUENCE` is an Oracle Object. You have other possibilities in others rdbms, like defining an [Auto_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)  columns in MySQL, etc. About creation from Java, think in `SEQUENCE` similar than `TABLES`, define it in design time.

Comment: SQL Server has `SEQUENCE` object too. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)