# MySQL - How to retrieve next available sequence value from a stored procedure when using table generator strategy?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, primary-key, sequence

I have a MySQL table which uses JPA [Table Generator strategy](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Table_sequencing) to retrieve the next available primary key value in the application code.

But there is a special case related to this table, in which I need to insert a new record to this table from a stored procedure. That means the stored procedure has to retrieve the next available PK value for this table before inserting the record.

Although I know how to retrieve the next available PK value using the table generator strategy, I am not sure how to retrieve the next available PK value from a stored procedure.

Do I just have to use a

```
SELECT current value + 1 FROM (Table Generator Table) 
WHERE (table generator record for this table) FOR UPDATE;
```

and 
then

```
UPDATE (Table Generator Table) SET current value = current value + 1
WHERE (table generator record for this table)
```

?

Is there any better approach?

Comment: One idea is to leave the the PK column unspecified for the INSERT statement, let the database fill in the missing value via autoincrement, and optionally retrieve the value it came up with using the RETURNING clause (or equivalent MYSQL method).

Comment: The problem in using autoincrement is, this application is used for both Oracle and MySQL. We use a different ORM files to map the generator strategy when we use the application in either Oracle or MySQL. Therefore we have to add many if conditions etc and customize the code, if we use AUTOINCREMENT for MySQL, but use sequence strategy for Oracle.

Comment: I see. Table Generator requires an independent second transaction, though, to obtain the sequence number, right? Not sure if that is possible to do from within a MySQL stored procedure.

Comment: Or, you could go ahead and do this within the same transaction. Would still work, but potentially cause concurrency issues (everyone needs to wait for your transaction to complete before they can get the next number).

Comment: Also, if you are on Oracle 12, you can finally let the database handle it as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18153440/14955

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is good to have that kind of feature in Oracle also. It seems some JPA providers uses a separate connection to retrieve the sequence value from the table, according to the documentation. Possibility of concurrency issues is a problem. But I think it should be rare for my use case, but still possible.