# Sql trigger "column list not valid for this trigger type"

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle12c

So I want to create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_primary_key
AFTER INSERT ON CAJ
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (ID_CAJ IS NULL)
DECLARE
maximum NUMBER;
BEGIN
  maximum := SELECT MAX(ID_CAJ) FROM caj;
  if (maximum <> 0)
    UPDATE caj
    SET ID_CAJ = maximum + 1;
    WHERE CAJ_ID = NULL
    maximum = maximum +1;
END;
```

This error appears:

```
"invalid NEW or OLD specification"
*Cause:    An invalid NEW or OLD specification was given for a column.
*Action:   Re-specify the column using the correct NEW or OLD specification.
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't your `SET` clause be before the `WHERE`?

Comment: I am using Oracle 12c

Comment: @NullExceptio tried it same error

Comment: @nocturne It was more like a note for you, preventing you from asking another question.

Comment: @NullException not sure if I understood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle I suppose.  This is not correct:

```
AFTER INSERT OF ID_CAJ
IN caj
```

INSERT  inserts row[s]. Column list is not relevant here. It should be ON table name

```
AFTER INSERT ON CAJ
```

And if you want trigger which sets new primary key if inserted row has `NULL` value, see this topic for Oracle common way of doing it using `SEQUENCE` [create table with sequence.nextval in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle)

Comment: I got a new eror: `"invalid trigger specification"
*Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
*Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.`

Comment: Edit the question to show new trigger sql. Have you removed `IN caj` ?

Comment: removed IN caj eddited again

Comment: Please explain, what are you tying to achieve. I'm afraid we may end up with syntactically correct trigger which is doing bad things.

Comment: I want trigger which sets new primary key(ID_CAJ) if inserted row has unspecified this primary key(NULL).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should not specify "OF ID_CAJ" since it's after insert trigger and it's about row, not column

Comment: `AFTER INSERT ON CAJ` not helped new error:` The create TRIGGER statement is invalid`

Comment: And this could be a problem mentioned by @NullException - SET should be WHERE. Also sometime you are using column CAJ_ID, and sometime ID_CAJ. Should it be the same?

Comment: CAJ_ID was a typo, thanks, but new error appeared , I eddited question...SET should be WHERE? I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I noticed edit a bit later sorry. Please notice syntax for IF statement should be: 
IF condition THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition is TRUE...}
END IF;

Comment: Thanks for the if syntax corected...but error with new/old still remains, I wrote my aim of trigger in one of comments here.

Comment: Try to update "WHERE CAJ_ID = NULL" with "WHERE :NEW.CAJ_ID = NULL"

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Oh, and I suppose "SELECT MAX(ID_CAJ) FROM caj;" should also be updated to "SELECT MAX(:NEW.ID_CAJ) FROM caj;"

Comment: good point, but did not helped