# Unique value generation for primary key for multiple tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I do have 3 tables. I want to generate ID for each below table and that should be unique across each table.
Table1 ID - primary
ID
1 -> 2 -> 3
Table2 ID - primary
ID
4 -> 5
Table3 ID - primary
ID
6 -> 7 -> 8
Whenever a new entry is made to the above tables it should generate unique values across the tables
For next time when I want to insert 2 records to table 1 it should be
Table1 ID - primary
ID
9 -> 10.

Do we can create a trigger to accomplish this in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger on each table and create a [Sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

Then on the trigger on insert do something like:

```
   select seq.nextval 
     into :new.id
     from dual;
```

This was asked before. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613875/3021415)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON qname
  FOR EACH ROW
  -- Optionally restrict this trigger to fire only when really needed
  WHEN (new.qname_id is null)
DECLARE
  v_id qname.qname_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Select a new value from the sequence into a local variable. As David
  -- commented, this step is optional. You can directly select into :new.qname_id
  SELECT qname_id_seq.nextval INTO v_id FROM DUAL;

  -- :new references the record that you are about to insert into qname. Hence,
  -- you can overwrite the value of :new.qname_id (qname.qname_id) with the value
  -- obtained from your sequence, before inserting
  :new.qname_id := v_id;
END my_trigger;
```

Comment: Can you help me to create the trigger for the tables ? and how this sequence is linked to the trigger

Comment: @user2677675 I posted a sample I extracted from SO.

Comment: In real scenario I do have more than 20+ table.hence I need to create 20+ triggers. Is there any way that I can create a single trigger upon 20+ table to generate the seq no

Comment: @user2677675 No, you will have to create 20+ triggers. one on each table. They are almost the same, you can do that dynamically.