# Error pops up while creating the table

Tags: oracle

While creating this table am getting the error, can you help with this :

```
CREATE TABLE FIPR_MASTER ( 
   FIPR_Id   INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS 
      AS IDENTITY 
      (START WITH 100 
       INCREMENT BY 1 
       MINVALUE 100 
       NO MAXVALUE 
       NO CYCLE 
       NO CACHE 
       ORDER) PRIMARY KEY, 

   FIPR_NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   BU_NAME    VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   LOCATION VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   RECORD_SOURCE_NAME   VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
   PRIORITY_QUEUE  VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   STATUS  VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
   INDEXING_TYPE VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
   SOURCE_PATH  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
   DESTINATION_PATH  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
   COMMENTS VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL
   )
```

Error :

```
CREATE TABLE FIPR_MASTER ( 
   FIPR_Id   INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS 
      AS IDENTITY 
      (START WITH 100 
       INCREMENT BY 1 
       MINVALUE 100 
       NO MAXVALUE 
       NO CYCLE 
       NO CACHE 
       ORDER) , 

   FIPR_NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   BU_NAME    VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   LOCATION VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   RECORD_SOURCE_NAME   VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
   PRIORITY_QUEUE  VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   STATUS  VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
   INDEXING_TYPE VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
   SOURCE_PATH  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
   DESTINATION_PATH  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
   COMMENTS VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(FIPR_Id)
   )
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Which Oracle version? If I remember well, you can use this from 12c on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create table with sequence.nextval in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle)

Comment: If you want auto increment id, check this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle`

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..am using Oracle 11g

Comment: and when am removing the sequence creation part ..then am able to create the table ..but without making the FIPR_Id as a sequence .

Answer (score 2):

You've a few issues with your DDL statement:

1. The identity column must be declared before any inline constraints (`not null` counts as an inline constraint)
2. Seeing as you're declaring this as a primary key (of which, one of the definitions is that the pk columns are not null), there is no need to explicitly state `not null` anyway!
3. There should be no gaps between the NO and the MAXVALUE, CYCLE, and CACHE.

The following statement will work for you, assuming you are on 12.1 or above:

```
CREATE TABLE FIPR_MASTER ( 
   FIPR_Id   INT GENERATED ALWAYS 
      AS IDENTITY 
      (START WITH 100 
       INCREMENT BY 1 
       MINVALUE 100 
       NOMAXVALUE 
       NOCYCLE 
       NOCACHE 
       ORDER) PRIMARY KEY, 

   FIPR_NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   BU_NAME    VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   LOCATION VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   RECORD_SOURCE_NAME   VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
   PRIORITY_QUEUE  VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL, 
   STATUS  VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
   INDEXING_TYPE VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
   SOURCE_PATH  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
   DESTINATION_PATH  VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
   COMMENTS VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL
   );
```