# sql script not running

Tags: oracle, sequence

Here is a code snippet of a sql script which is giving me error,I have to generate a sequence on the primary_key of the table without using triggers in oracle:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE t1_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

DROP TABLE CPR_SOURCE_SYSTEM_METADATA;

CREATE TABLE CPR_SOURCE_SYSTEM_METADATA 

   (    
         SYSTEM_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL t1_seq.nextval,

         SYSTEM_NAME VARCHAR2(200),

         DATE_FORMAT VARCHAR2(200),

         CREATED_BY VARCHAR2(200),
         MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR2(200),
         CREATED_ON NUMBER(20),
         MODIFIED_ON NUMBER(20),
         IS_DELETED VARCHAR2(1),
         CONSTRAINT "CPR_SOURCE_SYSTEM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SYSTEM_ID")
 );
```

It is giving me the below error :

> DROP TABLE CPR_SOURCE_SYSTEM_METADATA
>              * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> SYSTEM_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL t1_seq.nextval,
>                                                 * ERROR at line 3: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Not able to figure out the error,can anyone help??

Comment: You cannot specify sequence name directly in create table. In Oracle 12c you can also declare an identity column. For all other versions u can use triggers. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create id with AUTO\_INCREMENT on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle)

Comment: that means we do not need to create any sequence specifically?

Comment: In 12c, if you wish to use an explicitly created sequence, instead of identity, one can default the sequence.nextval. In this case `SYSTEM_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT t1_seq.nextval`. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-sep/o53asktom-1999186.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SYSTEM_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL t1_seq.nextval,
```

The `t1_seq.nextval` segment is not valid - you cannot specify an auto-incrementing column like that.

The SQL parser is expecting to see:

```
SYSTEM_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
```

and throws the exception as the comma is not where it expects.

In Oracle 12c you can use an [identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222811/1509264) but in earlier versions you will either need to:

1. Use the sequence in the SQL insert statement;
2. Use a trigger to insert the correct sequence value; or
3. Create a stored procedure to handle inserts and manage the sequence through that (disallowing direct inserts that could bypass this).