# How to multiply rows in oracle query by count column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have example table:

```
OVERALL_COUNT | NAME | OTHER_ATTRIBUTE

1 | ABC | q
5 | ACB | w
2 | CBA | e
........
[many rows, like thousands]
```

Update: the rows in overall_count column are unknown, they are calculated by other query

I need to get specific result where names and other attributes duplicates by overall_count.

How I can write query to get result like this?

```
ABC | q
ACB | w
ACB | w
ACB | w
ACB | w
ACB | w
CBA | e
CBA | e
```

Comment: Please show us the actual starting table, not a distillate of it.

Comment: It seems to me that to know how many of items there are at the outset, we'd need to basically be _starting_ off with the expected output.

Comment: Original table just has many rows(like thousands) and other columns that can't be used for a helping. There are second_names, phone_number, adresses...
I thought there some function like group by but multiply

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen
The starts table is already has calculated overall_count. There is no base table where are overall calculating

Answer (score 2):

For 12c and above you may use lateral join:

> ```
> with a(OVERALL_COUNT, NAME, OTHER_ATTRIBUTE) as (
>   select 1, 'ABC', 'q' from dual union all
>   select 5, 'ACB', 'w' from dual union all
>   select 2, 'CBA', 'e' from dual
> )
> select a.*
> from a
>   cross join lateral (
>     select 1
>     from dual
>     connect by level <= a.overall_count
>   )
> order by name
> ```
>
> ```
> OVERALL_COUNT | NAME | OTHER_ATTRIBUTE
> ------------: | :--- | :--------------
>             1 | ABC  | q              
>             5 | ACB  | w              
>             5 | ACB  | w              
>             5 | ACB  | w              
>             5 | ACB  | w              
>             5 | ACB  | w              
>             2 | CBA  | e              
>             2 | CBA  | e
> ```

Or for 11 version:

> ```
> with b(
>   overall_count
>   , name
>   , other_attribute
>   , l
> ) as (
>   select a.*, 1
>   from a
>
>   union all
>   
>   select
>     overall_count
>     , name
>     , other_attribute
>     , l + 1
>   from b
>   where l < overall_count
> )
> select *
> from b
> order by name
> ```
>
> ```
> OVERALL_COUNT | NAME | OTHER_ATTRIBUTE |  L
> ------------: | :--- | :-------------- | -:
>             1 | ABC  | q               |  1
>             5 | ACB  | w               |  1
>             5 | ACB  | w               |  2
>             5 | ACB  | w               |  4
>             5 | ACB  | w               |  5
>             5 | ACB  | w               |  3
>             2 | CBA  | e               |  2
>             2 | CBA  | e               |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c98087d532f16408f856a7dc2d9966df)*

Comment: Note that `cross apply` is non-standard SQL. If you want to use a lateral join with standard  ANSI SQL use `cross join lateral` instead which Oracle also supports.

Comment: @astentx Thanks for reply. I think I must update question.
There is some correction: the rows in count column are unknown count. Thinking about writing stored procedure based on this answer. But if you know some simplier way it will be great.

Comment: @vladsrc There's no any predefined constants in this queries. They will generate as much rows as there is in the `OVARALL_COUNT` as exactly was asked in the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. As `connect by` is Oracle specific, it makes not much value, but I've edited the answer to conform standard syntax of this part

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join approach with the help of a sequence table:

```sql
WITH seq AS (
    SELECT 1 AS cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 FROM dual
)

SELECT t1.NAME, t1.OTHER_ATTRIBUTE
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN seq t2
    ON t2.cnt <= t1.OVERALL_COUNT
ORDER BY t1.NAME;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that I hard-coded a trivial sequence table with only 5 values (which happens to cover all your sample data).  [Check this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613846/create-table-with-sequence-nextval-in-oracle) for some more ideas on how to work with sequence tables in Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
this is a nice trick, but I doesn't know how many rows in overall_count can be. Its changing dynamically. Any other options please?

Comment: Then you need to show us the original table.  That table you _did_ show us indeed has the overall count in it.

Comment: original table just have many rows, like thousands... But I working with a small part of them. Small part of them with unkbown count. Looking for your answer I thinking about stored procedures. Maybe it will work for me.
I thought there is some simplier option, for example: select name, other_attributes from table multiplied by overall_count